# How to cache DNS in libsoup in Vala?

Tags: caching, https, dns, vala, http-caching

I am using libsoup in my Vala application to get data from Instagram API. But it takes about 10 seconds to load one page from it (while browser displays the same page in ~1-2 seconds). I thought initially that it is because of HTTPS (HTTPS pages load way longer that HTTP pages), but I figured out that most of the time it resolves my most.

So, the question is: is there any way I can cache DNS results to not resolve host every time I need a connection to it? Or is it possible?

Here is the function I'm using:

```
public string getResponse (string host) 
{
    var session = new Soup.Session ();
    session.ssl_strict = false;
    session.user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36";

    var message = new Soup.Message ("GET", host);
    message.tls_errors = GLib.TlsCertificateFlags.VALIDATE_ALL;
    message.network_event.connect((event) => {
        if (event == SocketClientEvent.RESOLVING) print("RESOLVING\n");
        if (event == SocketClientEvent.RESOLVED) print("RESOLVED\n");
        if (event == SocketClientEvent.CONNECTING) print("CONNECTING\n");
        if (event == SocketClientEvent.CONNECTED) print("CONNECTED\n");
        if (event == SocketClientEvent.PROXY_NEGOTIATING) print("PROXY_NEGOTIATING\n");
        if (event == SocketClientEvent.PROXY_NEGOTIATED) print("PROXY_NEGOTIATED\n");
        if (event == SocketClientEvent.TLS_HANDSHAKING ) print("TLS_HANDSHAKING \n");
        if (event == SocketClientEvent.TLS_HANDSHAKED) print("TLS_HANDSHAKED\n");
        if (event == SocketClientEvent.COMPLETE) print("COMPLETE\n");
    });

    print("start sending\n");
    session.send_message (message);
    print("stop sending\n");
    return (string) message.response_body.data;
}
```

and most of the time of loading is between "RESOLVING" and "RESOLVED.

Btw, I thought it's a good idea to set some field in GSettings to store Instagram API server IP and replacing host's hostname to that IP address, will that work? And if it will, how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote my getResponse function this way and now it works the way I wanted it to.

```
public string getResponse (string host) 
{ 
    var ip = loadAddress();
    if (ip == "")
        ip = resolveHost();

    var newHost = replaceHostWithIp(host, ip);

    var session = new Soup.Session ();
    session.ssl_strict = false;
    session.user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36";

    var message = new Soup.Message ("GET", newHost);
    message.tls_errors = GLib.TlsCertificateFlags.VALIDATE_ALL;  

    message.request_headers.append("Host", "api.instagram.com");

    session.send_message (message);

    if (loadAddress() == "")
        setAddress(ip);

    return (string) message.response_body.data;
}
```

where `loadAddress()` and `setAddress()` are functions which load IP from GSettings and sets it and `replaceHostWithIp()` is a function that replaces `api.instagram.com` with given IP address.

Comment: Now when instagram changes their IP address your code will never work again... Not a great solution. It might be more useful to try to figure out why your DNS is so slow: I'm pretty sure libsoup just uses GIO which ends up essentially calling `getaddrinfo()` and for some reason your operating system takes a very long time to resolve an address.

Comment: I know, I think I'll handle it later. Strange thing is, http://api.instagram.com resolves fast and https://api.instagram.com resolves very slow, although IP is the same, I think.

Comment: @jku btw, can you suggest me how to figure it out? I tried using libcurl instead of libsoup (I've read it's faster) and it had the same result, so I think it is not the library issue.

Comment: whoops, api.instagram.com links should start with http: and https:

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a while ago, and I solved it by using

```
session.set_proxy_resolver(null);
```

It seems like the default proxy resolver is too slow.